# How to store each query result in another array and returning at the end to controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

The problem im facing is that im getting data in the function from my controller function and in side my model function i have to get result using query using dynamic value of chanel . chanel id will be coming from each check box on my view in HTML. when ever i check CHECKBOX 1 it retrieves the data but for the second check box it gives nothing i want to itrate the query and save result in final query .PS im newbe in CI framework.

```
function get_data()
        {
            $serial = $this->input->post('serial');
            $chanel = $this->input->post('channel_id');

            $fi=explode(",", $chanel);

            $conditiondata=count($fi);
            $arr =array();
            for($i=0;$i<$conditiondata;$i++) {


                if($i==0)
            {


            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from `channels` WHERE `serial_id` = '$serial' AND `channel_name` = '$fi[$i]'");
                if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                    $arr[$i] = $query->result();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                    return false; 
                    }

            }
            else{
                return false;
                }
                }
            var_dump($arr);

            return $arr;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will solve your problem

remove `if($i==0)` in the `foreach`  condition you have set the condition for `0 key` that is why it is getting only one data of first `id`

```
for($i=0;$i<$conditiondata;$i++) 
{

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from `channels` WHERE `serial_id` = '$serial' AND `channel_name` = '$fi[$i]'");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        $arr[$i] = $query->result();
    }
    else
    {
       return $arr = array(); 
    }            
}
var_dump($arr);
```